# Fundamental theorem of calculus for a function depending on the same variable of integration bound.

Tags: calculus, integration, bounds-of-integration

Let $r, a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f\in L_1 ([a,b])$. Define the function $$F : [a, b] \to\mathbb{R}$$
as
$$F (x) = r + \int_{r}^{x} f(t)\,dt$$
(so that $F (a) = r$). The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus pt. I states
$$F'(x) = f(x).$$

My question is:
If a function $g$ is defined in two variables with domain $[a, b]\times [a, b]$ and
$$G(x):= r + \int_{r}^{x} g(x,t)f(t)\,dt,$$
then what is $G'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 
$$
  G'(x) = g(x,x)f(x) + \int_r^x \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,t) f(t)\,dt.
$$
This follows from the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Thanks! someday I may understand the difference between $d$ and $\delta$.